# Pandas and Matplotlib: Can't get the stackplot to work with using Matplotlib on the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Dataframe object coming from a SQL-Query that looks like this:

```
            Frage/Diskussion          ...           Wissenschaft&Technik
date                                  ...                               
2018-05-10                13          ...                              6
2018-05-11                28          ...                              1
2018-05-12                11          ...                              2
2018-05-13                21          ...                              3
2018-05-14                30          ...                              4
2018-05-15                38          ...                              5
2018-05-16                25          ...                              7
2018-05-17                23          ...                              2
2018-05-18                24          ...                              4
2018-05-19                31          ...                              4

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

I want to visualize this data with a Matplotlib stackplot in python.

What works is following line:

```
df.plot(kind='area', stacked=True)
```

**What doesn't work is following line:**

```
plt.stackplot(df.index, df.values)
```

The error I get with the last line is:

**"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (6,) "**

Obviously the last line with the 10 rows x 6 columns is passed into the plotting function.. and I can't get rid of it.

Writing out each column by hand is also working but not really what I want since there will be many rows later on.

```
plt.stackplot(df.index.values, df['Frage/Diskussion'], df['Humor'], df['Nachrichten'], df['Politik'], df['Interessant'], df['Wissenschaft&Technik'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is that `df.values` is a column by row array. To get the form you want you need to transpose it. Fortunately, that is easy. Replace `df.values` by `df.values.T`! So in your  code replace:

```
plt.stackplot(df.index,df.values)
```

with

```
plt.stackplot(df.index,df.values.T)
```